# How to update the iOS platform with out removing existing platform

Tags: ios, cordova

How to update the iOS platform with out removing existing iOS platform.

In cordova based project currently used iOS platform 4.2.1. So, needs to update iOS 4.5.2 or higher version.

I have used this following commands

```
cordova platform update ios@4.5.4 --save and 
cordova platform update ios@4.5.4
```

But it is showing an error as below.

> ```
> Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@4.5.4
> Updating ios project...
> (node:34228) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: An in-place platform update is not supported. 
> The `platforms` folder is always treated as a build artifact.
> To update your platform, you have to remove, then add your ios platform again.
> Make sure you save your plugins beforehand using `cordova plugin save`, and save a copy of the platform first if you had manual changes
> ```
>
> in it.
>         cordova plugin save
>         cordova platform rm ios
>         cordova platform add ios
>
> ```
> (node:34228) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
> ```
>
> function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled
>   promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict`
>   (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
>   (rejection id: 1)
>       (node:34228) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are
>   not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit
>   code.

Kindly let me know with out remove existing platform and needs to update the platform iOS 4.5.4 or later.

Comment: You can't. To update you have to remove first.

Comment: Thanks @Eric. kindly let me know till how much version we can update the version without removing existing.